# Concrete5 - What is the way to query the composers and retrieve a list with data

Tags: php, concrete5

I have in my concrete5 (LATEST) few composers (Blogs, news and more).
I want, **via php code** to query the database and retrieve list of composers entries.
On top of that, one of the news composers Fields is boolean - DisplayOnHomePage.

What I want to do is to show on the home page list of news (title and image) that was marked as DisplayOnHomePage=true.
Is there any official API to do that?

If there isn't, is there any other way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is using the pagelist, (block or model)

This allows you to filter pages by any number of things, including attributes.

```
$pl = new Pagelist();
$pl->ignoreAliases();
$pl->filterByPath('/some/page');
$pl->filterByCollectionTypeHandle('some_handle');
$pl->filterByDisplayOnHomePage();
$pages = $pl->get($numofitems);
```

There are a ton of things that you can filter by, the only things you really need for this to work is the first and last line of that code.

Just so you know, thats using the model, not the block.

After you do that, `$pages` is an array of page objects.

Mike

Comment: Questions, how would he define the method filterByDisplayOnHomePage?;  Is some_handle means the page type?, thanks

Comment: filterByDisplayOnHomePage() is a "magic method" -- the page list class will automatically provide a method that is the CamelCase version of the attribute_handle (although I think it only does this if you've checked the "Field available in Dashboard Page Search." box for it in the dashboard attributes page).

Comment: @Mnkras, do you need to pass 1 into the filterByDisplayOnHomePage method (e.g. $pl->filterByDisplayOnHomePag(1);) ?

Comment: Nope, it will by default filter by if the value is true, (its a basic if statement basically)